# Instagram API Authentication approval Instagram_basic resource route

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

“Your screencast does not show a test user logging into Instagram in your app. Please update your screencast to show the complete login experience.”

I’m looking for some advice on how to proceed with facebook. I submitted my app for review to seek approval for Instagram’s instagram_basic resources route. Naturally, I was denied without much explanation on how to move forward. My app already has Facebook login working and approval. My question is how do I show a test user logging in when I don’t have access to the instagram_basic route to receive a token to authenticate our apps users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using graph API, there is a test mode in which all permissions work for the test account you have linked it to. Take a screenshot of login flow, if you use chrome incognito mode, then the facebook login page will appear and you can capture the entire flow.

Answer (score 1):

In the initial login via FB they will ask for the permission approval once you approved then no more you will see this popup for same FB account. The best way is below (Uninstall the app for the test user or admin & restart the process)

[image]